# Where can I set build action to "AndroidResource"?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It all started when I wanted to customize the Notification icon of my program. The icon is located in `drawable` folder and I need pass it to `SetSmallIcon` function as integer type (resource id).

Inside my Xamarin.Android project I have file `AboutResources.txt` with the following hint:

> In order to get the build system to recognize Android resources, set
>   the build action to "AndroidResource".  The native Android APIs do not
>   operate directly with filenames, but  instead operate on resource IDs.
>   When you compile an Android application that uses resources,  the
>   build system will package the resources for distribution and generate
>   a class called "Resource" that contains the tokens for each one of the
>   resources included.

But I cann't understand, where I can set **the build action**. I didn't find anything like that in the options of Project.

May be I just have missed some button or checkmark?

**PS**:

Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Just right click on the icon file that you put into the drawables folder -> you ll be able to see the option saying “build action”

Comment: @Saamer, thanks! it really is!

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: @Saamer, yes, it works fine! Thank)

Comment: Ok sweet. I put that answer below, so you can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just right click on the icon file that you put into the drawables folder -> you ll be able to see the option saying “build action”